# Jenkins scripted pipeline: must specify $class with an implementation of class jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a jenkins multibranch-pipeline. Apparently it checked out the main repo successfully (files are visible in the workspace).

But then I called this method. Goal was to check out (in a dedicated subfolder) the following repository and the same branch that I checked out of the main repo (e.g. if main repo is checked out at "my-target-branch-name" then "bar" repo should also try to check out branch "my-target-branch-name", or "master" as fallback. In fact the whole use case is similar if not the same as the one described in the [documentation of the resolveScm step (page might load slowly, be patient)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#resolvescm-resolves-an-scm-from-an-scm-source-and-a-list-of-candidate-target-branch-names)

```
checkout resolveScm(source: git(url: 'git@example.com:foo/bar.git', credentialsId: 'xxx'), targets: [env.BRANCH_NAME, 'master'])
```

However I got an error:

```
16:40:38  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: must specify $class with an implementation of class jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:574)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:473)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:302)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
16:40:38    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
16:40:38    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
16:40:38    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
16:40:38    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
16:40:38    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
16:40:38    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
16:40:38    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
16:40:38  Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {source={GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=jenkins.donotreply@example.com, GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=Jenkins, GIT_BRANCH=origin/master, GIT_COMMIT=xxx, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=jenkins.donotreply@example.com, GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=Jenkins, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH=master, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=yyy, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT=yyy, GIT_URL=git@example.com:foo/bar.git}, targets=[my-target-branch-name, master]} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.ResolveScmStep
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:302)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:193)
16:40:38    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
16:40:38    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
16:40:38    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
16:40:38    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
16:40:38    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
16:40:38    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
16:40:38    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
16:40:38    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
16:40:38    at fooBar.call(fooBar.groovy:14)
16:40:38    at fooBar.call(fooBar.groovy:258)
16:40:38    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
...
```

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the complete definition of Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {

    agent { label 'small || big' }

    stages {

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "ls -la"
                sh "rm -rf secondrepo && mkdir secondrepo"
                dir('secondrepo') {
                    checkout resolveScm(source: git(url: 'git@example.com:foo/bar.git', credentialsId: 'xxx'), targets: [env.BRANCH_NAME, 'master'])
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that there is a clash when one calls `git(...)` in their script.
The `source` parameter of `resolveScm` expects an instance of `jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource`. However, if one calls `git()` such as in the documentation, then it seems to rather match the [functionName in GitStep](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitStep.java#L109) and [create](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitStep.java#L85) an instance of [GitSCM](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java) which is **not** a subclass of SCMSource which is wrong.
Instead, by calling `git`, it should have matched the [`git` symbol in GitSCMSource](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitSCMSource.java#L422)

So, in order to get around this issue I enforced the instantiation of a `GitSCMSource` by specifying the arguments as a map:

```
checkout resolveScm(source: [$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote: 'git@example.com:foo/bar.git', credentialsId: 'xxx', traits: [gitBranchDiscovery()]], targets: [env.BRANCH_NAME, 'master'])
```